# Duplicate mouse pointer on second monitor on Ubuntu 17.10 on wayland

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, wayland, mouse-pointer, 17.10

I have a problem when setting up a second monitor in Ubuntu on Wayland only when the monitor is set to left of the screen.

[image]

this goes away when switching to X11.

Comment: i have the same problem. but, second pointer in some cases goes away... and returns)

Comment: in my case it shows when i am on the top left corner of my main monitor

Comment: Also seeing this only when in top left of my main monitor cursor is duplicated on bottom right (based on intended orientation of the monitor)/top right (based on actual orientation of monitor) of my secondary monitor. I'm not on Ubuntu, however -- I'm on Fedora with wayland.

Comment: It is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1724977

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans answer the question so I can mark your response as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re describing a known Wayland bug, which affects me too. It is rergistered on Launchpad as [bug 17424977](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1724977). As of today (April 6th, 2018), a fix has been released [upstream](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/85). There are therefore three workarounds:

- wait until the change propagates to Ubuntu and try to ignore this annoying second cursor on your left screen. Or better, since it’s free software: if you can, help Ubuntu implement the change
- switch to  a recent enough (i.e. brand new) branch of Wayland, which has the bugfix
- switch to X11